# Davidson, events, and states

Tags: ontology, semantics, events

Davidson argues that events are individuals. According to him, the meaning of **Brutus stabbed Caesar** is **∃e.stab(e,Brutus,Caesar)**, that is, there was a stabbing, Brutus did it, and Caesar underwent it. Likewise, **Caesar died** means **∃e.die(e, Caesar)**. Is there a reason not to view states as individuals, too? Something like **∃s.dead(s, Caesar)** for **Caesar is dead**? One could then say, for example, that

> die(e, Caesar) ≡ ∃s1,s2.change(e, s1, s2) ∧ alive(s1, Caesar) ∧ dead(s2, Caesar)

just as we can say

> kill(e, Brutus, Caesar) ≡ ∃e′.cause(e, Brutus, e′) ∧ die(e′, Caesar)

Coordination can also be construed as an individual

> ||Brutus stabbed Caesar and drank a beer|| = ∃e,e1,e2.and(e,e1,e2) ∧ ...

which gives us the possibility to have complex events (**I flew to Paris** is an event but it can be refined as going to the airport, entering the plane, etc.). Do I miss something that prevents us from wanting to reify states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is a typical consideration , why to not reify concepts (like states). This is the age old *Occam's Razor* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor):

> Entities must not be multiplied beyond necessity

In other words, we'd better not reify states, if we don't have to. Syntactically, we can still treat states as *pseudo-entities* using transformation rules, such as:

alive(x) <-> (Es)alive(s,x)

We seem to need reified events, more than we need reified states. Davidson's main reason for that, if I recall correctly, is that events are needed as the terms of *causal* relations. There seems to be  no similar motive for reified states, because states are not ingredients of causal relations (at least in Davidson's account of causality ).

Answer (score -1):

Your hair-splitting of events is no different from hair-splitting of other entities as well.

So you'd have:

> go(e, Brutus, Paris) ≡ go(e, leg(Brutus,left), Paris) ∧ go(e, leg(Brutus,right), Paris) ∧ go(e, arm(Brutus,left), Paris) ∧ go(e, arm(Brutus,right), Paris)  ∧ go(e, torso(Brutus), Paris) ...

You can split `Paris` in a similar manner too.

Davidsonian event semantics provides a formal way of notating the things you want to express. If you have good reason to split one event into several sub-events, do it. If you have good reason to split one entity into several sub-entities, do it.

States are just attributes of entities, and can be notated as ordinary predicates. The following statements refer to the same `Soup`, but in one event, it is a member of all `hot` things, and in another event, it is a member of all `cold` things.

> ∃e1.hot(e1, Soup)
>
> ∃e2.cold(e2, Soup)